# Querying a many to many relation with out a junction table

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, typeorm-datamapper

I have three entities in my application as below:

```
class Machine{
    id
    site_id 
    contract_id
    client_id
}

class Site{
    id 
}

class Contract{
    id
}
```

There is an entity named `Machine` and it has a `one_to_many` relationship with `Contract` and another `one_to_many` relation with another entity which is called `Site`. There is no direct relation between `Site` and `Contracts` and no junction table exists between them but `Machine` relates to both `Site` and `Contract` and also `client_id` is common between these entities and it works fine in 99% of times.

Now the business is asking for sth new, it needs the list of contracts of users, every contract should have the list of sites and site have a list of machines. it's would be great to have a raw SQL query or a solution that could be applied on `TypeOrm` query builder. I should mention that having a many_to_many relation between `Site` and `Contract` is not what I'm seeking due to some complexities it brings in my case.

Answer (score 0):

the machine could be used as a junction table in between
so in code we might define a relation like this one below

```
class site{
id
@ManyToMany(type=>Contract,contract=>contract.sites)
contracts:Contract[]
}

class Contract{
id
@ManyToMany(type=>Site,site=>site.contracts)
@JoinTable({name:"machine"})
sites:Site[] 
}
```